# I cannot launch shiny from web

Tags: r, shiny, gplots

I have installed shiny server following the tutorial:[here](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/install-opensource.). The server was started automatically, as shown in the following message:

```
shiny-server start/running, process 9376
```

I then created a folder on /etc/shiny-server and the file shiny-server.conf within it with the following configuration:

```
run_as shiny;

server {
listen 3838;

location / {
  utilization_scheduler 20 .9 3;
  site_dir /var/www/shiny-server;

  log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

  directory_index on;
  }
}
```

I created a folder called shiny-server under /var/www, and put a web app under a folder called dummy in /var/www/shiny-server (i.e. /var/www/shiny-server/dummy).
Finally, I started shiny-server again (sudo start shiny-server). I got the message the sever was running. However, when I opened the web browser and typed:

```
 http://localhost:3838/dummy
```

I got nothing.

I'm able to launch shiny apps from within R so I assume shiny is installed correctly. 
Can anybody help me solve my problem?

Comment: This is not about programming. Try posting your question at SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: Did you type "localhot" instead of "localhost"?

Comment: Thanks - I did use localhost

Comment: I'm not sure why you put a folder in /etc/shiny-server (the link to the tutorial you followed is broken), but I have a file at /etc/init/shiny-server.conf (one of the locations mentioned [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/)) that works for me.